# Python: Distributed computing on cloud for a python function

Tags: parallel-processing, bigdata, amazon-ecs, distributed-computing, dask-distributed

I have a Python function that is as simple as shown below. However, processing it one by one will take far too long.

So I'm considering splitting the input 'list of ids' into multiple lists in order to run it on a cloud parallelly. I believe AWS 'EC2' is one option, but configuring them one by one is too complexed. I'm wondering if there's any simple way to speed up my work?

```py
import many_packages
def myfunc(list_of_ids:List[int])->None:
    new_file = run preprocessing_with_pandas()
    # this stage needs a java run time and python's subprocess
    results = run_a_jar_with(new_file)
    upload_results_to_s3()
```

Expected result:

```py
many_lists = list_of_ids.split_into_chunks(chunk_size=100)

for i,c in enumerate(computers:"Cloud Instance"):
    c.computing(myfunc(many_lists[i]))
```

The current constraint is that I cannot use 'pyspark' because the data must be processed using a library that only supports pandas. So I'm doing research on another framework: 'Dask' to see how feasible it can be done with it.

Comment: So there are a couple of ways with varying complexity. Yes Dask can work, but it should not look like that where you pass work to an EC2 machine. In Dask, you should only interact with the scheduler, and it will delegate work to the workers. The assigning of work should be abstracted away from you. From AWS, you can spin a Dask cluster with EKS or ECS. Both are tricky in their own way, but should be easier than plain EC2. You can also use a provider like Coiled on top of your AWS account. EMR might be the easiest in terms of getting a managed Dask cluster.

Comment: followed the [instruction](https://yarn.dask.org/en/latest/aws-emr.html) but seems it's extremely slow to bootstrap, have been waiting for 25min. Is there anything I should be aware?

Comment: Yarn is slow but not that slow! Haha. Maybe you can't pull the machine because of resource quotas, so it just keeps trying. I assume your Docker image is simple. I also am assuming you're not using Spot instances which can add time. EMR is the one I have the least experience with the tools mentioned above. The Dask Discourse may be a better place to get assistance.